# method store() and update()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have to do a checking between the payment date and the seance date in my method store(). 
The method store() is OK!

```
$datePayment = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))
->whereDate('date_payment', ">" , $date_seance)
->first();

 if(isset($datePayment)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('error', 'There is a problem with the payment date! ');
}
```

My problem is in my function update(), I am stuck. When, I change the value of the date_seance, there is no checking.

```
$datePayment = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))
->whereDate('date_payment', ">" , $date_seance)
->first();

if(isset($datePayment)){
    return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
    ->with('error', 'There is a problem with the payment date! ');
}

else{
   $trainings = Training::find($id);
   $trainings->date_seance = $request->get('date_seance');
   ...
   $trainings->save();
   return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
    ->with('success', 'Update!')->withInput();
   }
```

I know my problem is here in the condition:

```
if(isset($datePayment)){
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
        ->with('error', 'There is a problem with the payment date! ');
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `datePaiement` - is that a typo? should be `datePayment`. But, can you please tell us what is not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: $datePayment  and $datePaiement? what's the difference between them?

Comment: @Raul: Sorry, I have from Belgium. I have edited my variable in english. My problem is that I don't understand the algorithm for do the checking as in my method store() ?

Comment: @Thamer: I modified my variable, the code is in French...

Answer (score 2):

If this is inside of an `update($id)` method, the change to the `date_seance` will have no checking because the query is looking for the wrong student's payments.

Before you look for your payment check, get the **training** model that is being updated inside the method (from the `$id` that was passed in).  This will have the correct student `id` from it's model.  So..

In the update method:

```
 $training = Training::find($id);
 $datePayment = Payment::where('fk_student', $training->fk_student) // NOT from $request
    ->whereDate('date_payment', ">" , $date_seance)
    ->first();
```

Instead of pulling in the student *who is writing the form*, make sure you are getting the payments from the student who is on the payment.

Comment: In fact, what interests me ... is that when I change a date of seance smaller than the date of payment. I must have an error message.

Comment: OK, what happens now?  No error message?  What exactly is `$date_seance`?  Is that coming from the form, and if so, have you parsed it with \Carbon ?

Comment: I don't have an error message I also used Carbon. In fact, I have a `payment date`, for example the `10/10/2019`, the `seance date`, can not be before that date for example the `04/10/2019`. I need to have a checking with a message explaining that there is a date error. In your code, I do not have an error message, I can change the date, there is no validation.

Comment: If you add in the same if-check you have directly below my code, this still doesn't work the way you want ?

Comment: So, using my code, you have a $datePayment object, and that object has a `date_payment` field?  So if you `dd($datePayment->date_payment)`, it comes up with a date?

Comment: I have a message `null`

Comment: OK, so this means when it hits the if-check for `isset()` it is NOT set and will pass the conflict.  Is there supposed to be a payment that was made for the original student of the training for a date that was after the `$date_seance`?  If so, you need to check two things: the database for the exact Payment that has the date for this student (look at the format), and dump the `$date_seance` to make sure it is 1) exists, 2) earlier than the database payment date, and 3) in the same format (or Carbon object).  If you are using the right FK student, this is really all that's left.

Comment: Thank you for your tips ...  I will correct this problem tomorrow because it's night. Good night Watercayman and thank you for your help.